# how to make a random selection from database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i am making a n application based on quiz
therefore i need to select data randomly from database
i m using sqlite
please help

Comment: You haven't specified it, but probably you also want to ensure that you don't get the same question twice in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check RANDOM() function, ex:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Table order by random()
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimise hits on the database, I would suggest reading out all of your questions into a data structure in memory (assuming there's not so many that it would consume all memory).

You could then shuffle the array using a decent shuffle algorithm and pop questions from the array to use.